# How to execute code if activity wasn't re-created from orientation rotation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, rotation, orientation

I am trying to make a quiz like an app. I have a class which is responsible for handling questions. I also have a view model that will hold these questions and other UI elements to assist with UI rotation changes.

My code looks something like this:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    var questions = quizModel.generateQuestions()
    quizViewModel.questions = questions
}
```

The thing is, I only want to do this when the activity was not re-created due to a rotation and change in the orientation of the device. This is because my view model will already hold my list of questions, so I don't need to generate another set of questions, just get the questions from the view model.

Is there some IF condition check I can try to do to execute the code above only when the activity wasn't re-created from orientation changes?

Comment: Why not generate the questions in the view model constructor? Then you won't have to manage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

if `savedInstanceState` is null then its the first time you activity is created, if non-null then it is being recreated.

Comment: Isn't it still possible for the bundle to be null on rotation? Because if you didn't override onSaveInstanceBundle and put nothing in that bundle, then savedInstanceState will still be null even on rotation.

Comment: There is always a Bundle after a rotation. If you didn't use `onSaveInstanceState`, it will be empty, not null.

Comment: @SmallGrammer this is a common technique for such problem, try it

Answer (score 0):

> Change your ViewModel to be something like this

```
class QuizModel():ViewModel(){
    // Change String? to your return type
    private var generatedQuestions : String? = null

    // Change String to your return type
    fun generateQuestions() : String {

        if (generatedQuestions == null) {
            // put your code here
            
            // at the end
            generatedQuestions = "the result of your code"
        }
        
        return generatedQuestions!!
    }

}
```

> and for your Activity

```
class yourActivity() {
    lateinit var question: yourType
    override fun onCreate() {
        question = quizModel.generateQuestions()
    }
}
```